# Two cartodb visualization on the same html page

Tags: carto, maps, html, dynamic

I need to display 2 maps separate by vertical line on the middle of the html, it means on diferents  and make some buttoms or aplicate the same zoom on both at the same time.

I managed to put one script code map on the first div but when I do the same to the other on the second div it invalidates the previous map and only shows the second map.

Im newbie on javascript. How can I solve this issue?

I know that with Iframe can do it but I need to make functionalities "outside" dinamically with 2 maps at the same time like zoom or filter's or a timelapse for the two at a time. Any ideas for this?

```
<div id="map1" style="border: 4px solid red; position: absolute; bottom: 181px; top: 0; z-index: 1; left: 0; right:50%;  padding: 0; margin: 0;">
</div>
<div id="map2" style="border: 4px solid blue; position: absolute; bottom: 181px; top: 0; z-index: 1; left: 50%; right: 0; padding: 0; margin: 0;">
</div>
```

```
<script>
  function main() {
    cartodb.createVis('map1', 'http://documentation.cartodb.com/api/v2/viz/2b13c956-e7c1-11e2-806b-5404a6a683d5/viz.json', {
        shareable: true,
        title: true,
        description: true,
        search: true,
        tiles_loader: true,
        center_lat: 0,
        center_lon: 0,
        zoom: 2
    })
    .done(function(vis, layers) {
      layers[1].setInteraction(true);
      layers[1].on('featureOver', function(e, latlng, pos, data) {
        cartodb.log.log(e, latlng, pos, data);
      });
      var map = vis.getNativeMap();
    })
    .error(function(err) {
      console.log(err);
    });
  }
  window.onload = main;
</script>

<script>
  function main() {
    cartodb.createVis('map2', 'http://documentation.cartodb.com/api/v2/viz/2b13c956-e7c1-11e2-806b-5404a6a683d5/viz.json', {
        shareable: true,
        title: true,
        description: true,
        search: true,
        tiles_loader: true,
        center_lat: 0,
        center_lon: 0,
        zoom: 2
    })
    .done(function(vis, layers) {
      layers[1].setInteraction(true);
      layers[1].on('featureOver', function(e, latlng, pos, data) {
        cartodb.log.log(e, latlng, pos, data);
      });

      var map = vis.getNativeMap();
    })
    .error(function(err) {
      console.log(err);
    });
  }
  window.onload = main;
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is not working because you have two "main" functions. You'd just need to use the two createVis methods inside one of them, and get rid of the other.

I have also renamed the variable "map" that you had inside each method, and associating each of the maps to a global variable (map1 or map2) in case you need to use them for something.

The working code is here.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>

    <style>
      html, body{
        height: 100%;
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
      }
    </style>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://libs.cartocdn.com/cartodb.js/v3/3.15/themes/css/cartodb.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map1" style="border: 4px solid red; position: absolute; bottom: 181px; top: 0; z-index: 1; left: 0; right:50%;  padding: 0; margin: 0;">
</div>
<div id="map2" style="border: 4px solid blue; position: absolute; bottom: 181px; top: 0; z-index: 1; left: 50%; right: 0; padding: 0; margin: 0;">
</div>

    <!-- include cartodb.js library -->
    <script src="http://libs.cartocdn.com/cartodb.js/v3/3.15/cartodb.js"></script>


    <!-- Drop your code between the script tags below! -->
    <script>

    function main() {

      var map1;
      var map2;
    cartodb.createVis('map1', 'http://documentation.cartodb.com/api/v2/viz/2b13c956-e7c1-11e2-806b-5404a6a683d5/viz.json', {
        shareable: true,
        title: true,
        description: true,
        search: true,
        tiles_loader: true,
        center_lat: 0,
        center_lon: 0,
        zoom: 2
    })
    .done(function(vis, layers) {
      layers[1].setInteraction(true);
      layers[1].on('featureOver', function(e, latlng, pos, data) {
        cartodb.log.log(e, latlng, pos, data);
      });
     map1 = vis.getNativeMap();
    })
    .error(function(err) {
      console.log(err);
    });

     cartodb.createVis('map2', 'http://documentation.cartodb.com/api/v2/viz/2b13c956-e7c1-11e2-806b-5404a6a683d5/viz.json', {
        shareable: true,
        title: true,
        description: true,
        search: true,
        tiles_loader: true,
        center_lat: 0,
        center_lon: 0,
        zoom: 2
    })
    .done(function(vis, layers) {
      layers[1].setInteraction(true);
      layers[1].on('featureOver', function(e, latlng, pos, data) {
        cartodb.log.log(e, latlng, pos, data);
      });

      map2 = vis.getNativeMap();
    })
    .error(function(err) {
      console.log(err);
    });
  }

    window.onload = main;
    </script>

  </body>
</html>
```