# Two maps using Carto and Leaflet with same events (zoom, pan, etc)

Tags: leaflet, carto, carto.js

I need a HTML page to compare two maps from Carto using Leaflet with same events, i.e. a Pan (or Zoom In/Out) event in Map1 aplicate the same in Map2.

I saw this example ([Two cartodb visualization on the same html page](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/162257/99942)) that show how can I use two maps at the same pages. But I need aplicate same events in both maps.

Comment: Have you seen the plugins at http://leafletjs.com/plugins.html#minimaps--synced-maps ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create and instantiate two maps (`map1` and `map2`), then you can assign a custom function to both maps after a certain event:

```
map1.on('event', function(e) {
  customFunction(map1, map2);
});

map2.on('event', function(e) {
  customFunction(map2, map1);
});
```

[Here](http://bl.ocks.org/ramiroaznar/3d3cd3d61a910705a0d534fb98d1b3bd) you have a working example.

Comment: Doesn't Carto use Leaflet?

Comment: Yes, it does. But also works with OL and GM.